# Linking a library which is compile time linked to another library

Tags: c++, c, unix, dynamic, hyperlink

I have a binary1 which is compile time linked to another library1.so
To add some functionality I have created library2.so which uses libas_sdk.so.

Functionality in library2.so works only if dlopen(libas_sdk.so) is success, else it returns normally and does other work.

Now library1.so has to use library2.so if required and use the new functionality.

I have tried multiple compile and link options but getting ldd or unresolved symbol errors.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please give the error msg when you got it. It will help other help you to identify the issue.

Comment: "compile time linked" - I think it's linked at link time. ;) Also, the wording is somewhat confusing, at least to me.

Comment: Be explicit about what you've tried in terms of "multiple compile and link options".  I know these things can be frustrating, but this post reads a little like you have given up and now just want to whine.

Answer (score 0):

dlopen() will return success, if the lib is already linked in.

Because library1.so has to use library2.so, you need to link both of them to binary1. (-llibrary1 -llibrary2)

From your question seems, that library2.so links in libas_sdk.so runtime. It happens probably when you call its some init_library2() or some function with some configuration data.

I think the problem is not with your linking, but with your binary1. This initialization of library2 (or library1) is what you do too early, or too late. IMHO your binary1 should be linked with a simple -llibrary1 -llibrary2 .